# Need code html5 slider, display value as calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, slider

I want to display the html5 slider value in a text box next to the slider.

The problem I'm facing is that I want the value of the slider multiplied by 2 for example.

For instance, the slider value will display 50, but the value in the text box will display 100. I am pretty new to this, have searched days on end without coming up with a solution.

Any ideas to solve this issue will greatly be appreciated.

Current code:

```
<input type="range" name="grade" orient="vertical min="0" max="1000" value="0" 
  step="50" onchange="showValue(this.value)" style="width: 20px; height: 400px; 
   -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; writing-mode: bt-lr;">
  <span id="range">0</span>
  People
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue) {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newValue;
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the value of the slider multiplied by 2

You can replace

```
onchange="showValue(this.value)"
```

with

```
onchange="showValue(2*this.value)"
```

This way you will always send double the value.

Comment: Thank you so much, sometimes its the simple things that gets overlooked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just another thing, what if I multiply by 0.14 , and would want the result rounded off?

Comment: To do a round off in JS we use Math.round(value). If you send 0.14*value, then inside the showValue(newValue){} function , do Math.round(newValue)

Comment: Would it be possible to have different values on different steps. For instance, at 50 multiply by 0.14, at 100 multiply by 0.12, at 150 multiply by 0.10?

Comment: Simply pass this.value to showValue() and in JS use a switch case on "value" like switch(value){ case 50 : newValue=value*0.14;break;....so on..}

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: Your original question is different from what you are asking in comments. You should ask it in a new question.